# Replace -84 in string: "my-name-is-dude-84" with '' by regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to Replace `-84` in a string: `my-name-is-dude-84` with '' Regex?
I means the last '-' + number

I tried :

```
string = 'my-name-is-dude-84'; 
let regex = /[^\-*][1-9]/; 
let specialChar = string.replace(regex, '');
```

then I received is my-name-is-dude-
I expect my string will be: my-name-is-dude

Comment: what did you mean, where you want to replace, did you use any language?

Comment: What do you mean remove? Regex can't remove anything. It's used to match, capture... But as @YCF_L point's out, you need a language (or tool) to use it.

Comment: @ClasG sr, i means "replace", I', using javascript regex

Comment: Is the number always at the end or can it be followed by more text?

Comment: OK, Regex can't replace either. But javascript can. Should be tagged with that. But this Q still lacks a lot of needed info. Is the number always `84`? What should it be replaced with? Have you searched (SO, google) and found anything? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but this is what you need to do (I guess)

```js
string = 'my-name-is-dude-84'; 
let regex = /-\d+$/; 
let specialChar = string.replace(regex, '');
document.write(specialChar);
```

Your `[^\-*]` tries to match all characters **but** `\`, `-` and `*`. Also `[1-9]` only matches one digit (between 1 and 9). Use `\d` (all digits), and add a `+` to make it match one or more. Also, adding an *end of string* anchor `$` to it makes it only match the hyphen+number at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex `(.*?)-\d+$`

## regex demo

**JavaScript demo**

```js
string = 'my-name-is-99-dude-84'; 
let regex = /(.*?)-\d+$/; 
let specialChar = string.replace(regex, "$1");
document.write(specialChar);
```